# how to retrieve all values each one in one line from app deployed in Cloud Foundry

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, awk, cloud-foundry

I am using a shell script to retrieve environment variables of an application.
an example of the variables and values:

```
User-Provided:
MLP_AUTH_CHECK_TOKEN_AUTH_HEADER: Basic eekmhdiuenéseégdfdtax=
MLP_AUTH_CHECK_TOKEN_URL: https://appName-Environment.Domain
MLP_UAA_PUBLIC_KEY: -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
bababbabababababababababababababababababababababbbabababababababababababababababababababab
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
MLP_UAA_SERVER_URL: https://appName-Environment.Domain
RUN_MODE: STAGING

No running env variables have been set

No staging env variables have been set
```

I used this command to retrieve the values: `cf env appName | awk '/User-Provided/,/No staging env variables have been set/' |  cut -f2,3 -d" " | tail -n +2 | head -n -4`

```
        Basic eekmhdiuenéseégdfdtax=
        https://appName-Environment.Domain
        -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
        bababbabababababababababababababababababababababbbaba
        -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
        https://appName-Environment.Domain
        STAGING
```

here, the result is not that good because the token is split into three lines, I will not get it in one line, also if I cut based on colon I will get the same with space at the beginning of each line result.

Could please help me to use a general solution that retrieves the values each one in one line?

note that I have diff apps and this situation is with one app, it may differ from one to another one, what I need is a solution that works in general

Thank you in advance

Comment: show the desired output

Comment: the disered output is the second one, but when i save it file it will store  the key in three lines, because it is outputed in three lines however it is only one filed in cloud foundry, but in 3 line in textarea in CF

Comment: what token are you trying to retrieve? Is this `uaac` token? Or is this `cf cli` token?

Answer (score 0):

For `cf cli` token, you can do

> $> cat ~/.cf/config.json | grep AccessToken

If its `uaac` token, you can do

> $> uaac target  --skip-ssl-validation
>
> $> uaac token client get [UAA_CLIENT_ID] -s [UAA_CLIENT_SECRET]
>
> $> export MY_TOKEN=$(uaac context | grep ".*access_token: " | sed -n -e "s/^.*access_token: //p")

Comment: `cf oauth-token` is another option for getting a valid token.